# input element larger than specified

Tags: html, css

I created an input element of type text and gave it a width of 90px and when I do this bit of code to find the width it does return me 90px, datafield is the variable where I store the reference to the element

```
  var firstWidth = theDatafields.eq(0).css("width");       
    console.log("the first " + firstWidth);
```

but when I actually check the element via dev console and hover over the element when I am inspecting the element it gives me 94px. Any ideas where the extra 4px is coming from?

Comment: I want to say that the input has an inherent border element that's 2px wide and only the interior text input area has width 90px.

Comment: include a fiddle please.

Comment: ok. So all element must have an inherent border and must be considered when modifying size to fit a container.

Comment: Using the console to check an element will apply borders/padding.  Using `.css("width")` gets the width without borders/padding - [more here](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

Comment: if you accepted my answer, you can also give it a `+1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its the `border`, which is `2px` on each side, to make it exactly `90px` give it a `width` of `86px`.

to see this yourself check the `layout` in a developer tool (`f12`), such as `firebug` (for `firefox`), or the default one in `chrome`.

Answer (score 1):

The total width occupied by an element, not counting its margins, is the width of its content plus the widths of left paddding, right padding, left border, and right border. The CSS `width` property sets, by default, by CSS specifications and in “standards” mode in browsers, only the content width.

The default styling of an `input` element varies. You may have tested in Chrome, which has no default horizontal padding and 2px borders, so the total width is 2px + 90px + 2px = 94px. Testing on Firefox, you would get 1px + 2px + 90px + 2px + 1px = 96px, since it uses by default 1px border and 2px padding. On IE, you get 94px, but on a different basis than on Chrome: IE has 1px border and 1px horizontal padding (and, oddly enough, 2px vertical padding).

What you get from libraries like jQuery depends on how it has been written, and may depend on its version and your way of using it. In plain JavaScript, the total width of an element (content plus padding plus border, but excluding margin) can be found, in pixels, in the property `offsetWidth`. (The `clientWidth` property has the width without borders.)

The morale is that if you want to be pixel-perfect, you would need to set both padding and border width explicitly. But beware that browsers behave oddly. They have their own special ways of rendering `input` elements, and if you interfere with their border settings, you might affect the border in a way you didn’t mean to. Just setting, say, `border-width: 1px` may also affect the border *style*. So to get the same rendering across browsers, possibly making the controls look different from their normal look in each browser, you would need to set `border-style` and `border-color`, too.

P.S. If you try to fix the dimensioning with `box-sizing: border-box` (which should be browser default according to HTML5 drafts, but isn’t), you introduce yet another browser dependency: Chrome and IE honor it, Firefox doesn’t.

Answer (score 0):

2px of borders on each side? See: `box-sizing`